# Acts 6:3 -Does a person full of "the Spirit" still need wisdom?

Tags: acts, translation-philosophy, pneumatology

1. What does the men "full of (the)Spirit mean,"full of the Holy Spirit?
2. Can the men full of "**the** **S**pirit" (=**the Holy Spirit**) as rendered in all Eng. Translations,lack anything?

(In all English Versions, **πλήρεις πνεύματος**, translated as "full of **the** **S**pirit"-is interpolation by the translators - refers to the Holy Spirit. The Holy Spirit is the very source of all the powers and wisdom.)

3. Should translate **πλήρεις πνεύματος** as "**full of spirit**" which  the Holy Spirit, the Giver "fills with" the believers? - e.g.,Bezalel & Oholiab -Ex. 28:3;36:1;35:34; Saul, 1 Sam 10:10; 120 people in the upper Room, Acts2:4;Peter and Stephen (Acts 4:8, 7:55);Paul (Acts 13:9).

**Text (ESV)**:

Acts 6:3 - "Therefore, brothers, pick out from among you seven men of good repute, full of the Spirit (**πλήρεις πνεύματος**) and of wisdom, whom we will appoint to this duty.

Comment: This is where translators deliberately pervert language for their theology, as if "full of spirit" will undermine the trinity or the personhood of the spirit. The spirit seems very awkward in the sentence. Full of spirit and wisdom. This should be the plain text. None of the versions renders like that https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/acts%206:3

Comment: "The Holy Spirit is the very source of all the powers and wisdom" - Please clarify.  Where in Scripture is this stated?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, we must first understand what is meant by “the Spirit” (Πνεύματος) with which the person is full.

In the New Testament, there are two usages of πνεῦμα:

1. God the Holy Spirit (τὸ πνεῦμα/τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον)
2. “holy spirit” (πνεύματος ἁγίου) - power, gifts of the Holy Spirit, etc.

There is a distinction between The Holy Spirit and holy spirit:

a. The Spirit/The Holy Spirit (τὸ πνεῦμα/τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον) - with the definite article in Greek and English, and capitalized H and S in English - is an exclusive and specific designation for God, the Holy Spirit, the Comforter. He is the subject of working/doing and an agent by which He accomplishes the works of God’s kingdom. He equips and empowers us to be witnesses of Jesus Christ to the end of the world.

b. πνεύματος ἁγίου (holy spirit): In the NT, πνεύματος ἁγίου is used in pair with natural elements such as water, fire, and wine. It denotes πνεύματος ἁγίου as something we can receive/impart as evidenced by Jesus when He said: “He breathed on them and said, “Receive πνεύματος ἁγίου (holy spirit)” - John 20:22.
Jesus also relates receiving πνεύματος ἁγίου to receiving the power of the Holy Spirit, and Peter to receiving spiritual gifts (Acts 2:4; 38).

In 1 Corinthians Chapter 12, Paul talks about the Holy Spirit giving various spiritual gifts for building up and encouraging the Church. Paul gives a list of gifts (v. 8 -10):
utterance of wisdom;
utterance of knowledge;
faith;
healing;
working of miracles;
prophecy;
ability to distinguish between spirits;
various kinds of tongues;
interpretation of tongues.

In some ways, spiritual gifts are like smartphone apps. They are God’s means of empowering His children for doing His work. Each gift operates separately within its own domain of function. Being filled with “holy spirit” does not mean having all gifts; having faith does not necessarily mean possessing spiritual wisdom.

**In summary**, for a deacon, wisdom and being full of spiritual power are essential for carrying out there duty.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few different questions, and I will endeavor to answer each: Does the writer of Luke intend us to understand the deacons as being filled with some impersonal substance/essence by the Holy Spirit to access spiritual gifts? If so, would 'full of spirit' be a good translation? Does a person full of "the Spirit" still need wisdom?

**Does the writer of Luke intend us to understand the deacons as being filled with some impersonal substance/essence by the Holy Spirit to access spiritual gifts?**

To get the elephant out of the room straight away, for the Holy Spirit to create holy spirit seems to be willfully confusing. Since God is not the author of confusion then that seems off.

But more particularly, the best verse for your "The Spirit -> spirit -> gift" argument looks to me to be Acts 2:4 where we have "holy spirit -> Tongues <- The Spirit".

> Acts 2:4 (ESV) And they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit gave them utterance.

Straight away, one has to ask why is The Holy Spirit (as in Acts 1) now being The Spirit at His first mention of Pentecost? The traditional response is is that He is called Holy Spirit at His first mention and The Spirit at His second mention within the same sentence.

Secondly, Acts 1 makes clear that they are in communication the The Holy Spirit and Acts 1:8 makes clear that The Holy Spirit is still to come upon them. In Acts 2:17, Peter has said the events of 2:4 are the fulfilment of The Spirit of God being poured out onto all flesh. If one understands that is is not The Holy Spirit that the disciples have been filed with in 2:4, then one has two questions that Luke fails to answer? What is this "holy spirit"? Why does Luke not narrate the pouring out of The Holy Spirit? The natural explanation is that that which is poured "τοῦ Πνεύματός" and that that which fills "Πνεύματος  Ἁγίου" are one any the same.

Having accepted the doctrine of The Holy Spirit that Luke presents us with in the first two chapters of Acts (Pentecost very much being a turning point), when we come to Acts 6:3 (this still being the first flush of the empowered church before martyrdom and scattering) that it is this awesome Holy Spirit with which they are filled.

In addition, if one objects to God being locally bound them since also contradicts the clear teaching of scripture of His being present in the Tabernacle and then the Temple. The Holy Spirit also is clearly described as alighting on Christ

**If so, would 'full of spirit' be a good translation?**

Even were that not so, then this would still not be a good translation because "full of spirit" already has an English meaning. [Theasaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/full%20of%20spirit) (and I had to change search engine as my current was too personalised) gives a list of synonyms such as plucky or fearless. These may describe the Deacons to a certain extent, but it does not mean what either of us thinks Luke is saying.

It would be better to say "full of spirit-" or "full of spirit-". In short, to construct a new term for your technical, mechanical understanding of "holy spirit".

**Does a person full of "the Spirit" still need wisdom?**

The plain reading of Acts 6:3 is "yes", since otherwise their search would have a redundancy. Generally, in Acts we see this filling involving tongues, comfort, joy, and insights to particular situation. Not really general wisdom.

Nor elsewhere in The Bible do we see these two things intertwine. In addition, Paul makes clear in first Corinthians that one can have spiritual gifts like tongues and prophecy and lack the more important such as love.

Answer (score -1):

Every Christian has the mind of Christ. If they have read the Bible the Holy Spirit will bring scripture to their remembrance and this is the wisdom provided in the word of knowledge for example, something brought to mind that you already have knowledge of.  The word of Wisdom is for things you need to know but don’t know yet, or help to create understanding by pulling things together that to you don’t seem related but can solve your problem.  This is the Holy Ghost working in you.  If you ask for the gift of the infilling of the Holy Spirit, you will receive it, if you have obeyed the gospel and fully repented, Acts 5:32